# Segmentation Fault in the Following Program for string comparisons

Tags: c, string, pointers, buffer-overflow, strcmp

I am getting segmentation fault for the following code. The logic of the  program that it should accept the correct password (`"abcd"`) and it should deny  access if entered any other password, but I am still getting a segmentation fault after I enter wrong password (eg: `"acdc"` or `"ancgff"`).I get proper response for passwords like `"abc"` or `"xyz"` where I get "access denied" message.

Please help me , unable to understand why I am getting this error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>        

int check(char *password)
{
    char pin_buffer[4];

    int authority = 0;

    strcpy(pin_buffer,password);

    if(strcmp(pin_buffer,"abcd")==0)

        authority=1;
    return authority;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    if(argc < 1)
    {           
        printf(argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    if(check(argv[1]))
    {
       printf("access granted");
    } 
    else
    {
        printf("access denied};
}
```

Comment: what's the point of `pin_buf ` ? why don't you just do `if(strcmp(pin,"abcd")==0)`

Comment: use strncpy command in place of strcpy, to avoid segmentation faults due to length mismatch.

Comment: I fell one should learn debugging to become good programmer. You can use GDB to debug it, it will give you more insights about what is happening.

Comment: Hey resolved the issue , thanks a lot.

Comment: the `pin_buffer[]` is 4 bytes long, so it can hold a string of 3 bytes (plus the NUL terminator byte)  so any supplied password greater than 3 bytes will overrun the buffer, resulting in undefined behavior.  That can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define

```
char pin_buf[4];
```

with a pre-decided size of `4` and then, without any check, you use

```
 strcpy(pin_buf,pin);
```

the moment `pin` has more than 3 elements (and a terminating null), you'll be overrunning the boundary of allocated memory while attempoting to copy which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That is why, you observe

> *"...I am still getting a segmentation fault after I enter wrong password (eg: `"acdc"` or `"ancgff"`).I get proper response for passwords like `"abc"` or `"xyz"`"*

That said, you don't need the `pin_buf` at all. The operations you intend to perform can be done with `pin` itself.